# Classification using covariance matrix descriptors and parallel processes

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, svm, video-processing, covariance

I am making a fire detection program to detect fire in real time video feed. I have divided the frame (320*240) to 16*16 blocks and extracted regions of interest using the initial color mask. Now I have covariance matrices of dimension 10*10 with the required features. The distance between two matrices can be calculated using log-euclidean method. How to train an SVM machine where my sample data is a matrix, not a 1-D vector?

Also, the matrix has been obtained by averaging the features of 5 consecutive frames. Is it possible to run the classification as a parallel process while the features of the next 5 frames are being extracted?

Comment: Process-level paralellism is too slow for real time applications. Instead, you can parallelize the tasks of feature extraction and classification by using multi-threading. Unfortunately, Matlab doesn't have sufficient support of multithreading to do that. If you must have parallelism, I suggest you'll move to the project to Python with OpenCV.

Comment: You can treat each matrix as a 1-D vector, in Matlab with `(:)`